# Sylius e-commerce issue with applying CK Editor

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, textarea, e-commerce, sylius

I would be very thankful if somebody might help me with some stuffs about CKEditor on symfony ( sylius e-commerce project ).

Things I want to do are:

I am wondering how I could replace standard textarea on my sylius admin dashboard panel with ckeditor textarea? For example

[image]

I want to replace that standard textarea with advanced text area using ck editor..

so if somebody might help me I would be really thankful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this on next way :
1) EDIT FILE "StaticContetType.php", find a textarea and edit it on a this way:

```
  ->add('body', CKEditorType::class, [
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'sylius.form.static_content.body',
        ])
```

and u get rich ckeditor textarea instead of that simple one =)

Answer (score 0):

just insert this in your backend layout view..

```
        <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.10/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('textarea').each(function() {
                CKEDITOR.replace($(this).attr('id'));
            })
        </script>
```